# } expected partial view razor error

Tags: razor, syntax-error, partial-views, umbraco7

I have code as below in umbraco partial view. Even though { } pairs matches, it shows the error i.e. } expected.

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{  
var langstr = "All";
var pageSize = 6;
var max_pages=0;
try
{
    if (@ViewData["storylang"] == null)
    {
        langstr = "";
    }
    else
    {
        langstr = @ViewData["storylang"].ToString();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    langstr = "";
}

var pageIndex = (int)@ViewData["page_index"]; 
dynamic selected;

if (@ViewData["curpage"] != null)
{

    var id = (int)@ViewData["curpage"];
    var currentNode = Umbraco.TypedContent(id);
    selected = currentNode.Children.Where("Visible");


   if(langstr != ""){
        selected = currentNode.Children.Where("Visible").Where("language=\"" + @langstr + "\"");
        max_pages = currentNode.Children.Count();

        <ul>
            @foreach (var story in selected.Take(pageIndex * pageSize))
            {

               <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="@story.Url" class="\""st-text"\">@story.Name</a></li>
            }
        </ul>

    }

}
else
{
    selected = CurrentPage.Children.Where("Visible");
    max_pages = CurrentPage.Children.Count();
    if(selected.Any()){
        <ul>
            @foreach (var story1 in selected.Take(pageIndex * pageSize))
            {
                <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="@story1.Url" class="st-text">@story1.Name</a></li>
            }
        </ul>

    }
}


}
```

What is the issue with code? Can anyone solve the same? Where am I wrong? I have spend a lot behind this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. It was mixing code and rendering blocks...
so here is the solution.

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{  
var langstr = "All";
var pageSize = 6;
var max_pages=0;
try
{
    if (ViewData["storylang"] == null)
    {
        langstr = "";
    }
    else
    {
        langstr = ViewData["storylang"].ToString();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    langstr = "";
}

var pageIndex=1;
if(ViewData["page_index"]!=null)
{
pageIndex=   (int)@ViewData["page_index"]; 
}
dynamic selected;
}

@if (ViewData["curpage"] != null){

var id = (int)ViewData["curpage"];
var currentNode = Umbraco.TypedContent(id);
selected = currentNode.Children.Where("Visible");


if(langstr != ""){
    selected = currentNode.Children.Where("Visible").Where("language=\"" + @langstr + "\"");
    max_pages = currentNode.Children.Count();
    <ul>
        @foreach (var story in selected.Take(pageIndex * pageSize))
        {

            <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="@story.Url" class="st-text">@story.Name</a></li>
        }
    </ul>

}
 else{
    selected = currentNode.Children.Where("Visible");
    max_pages = currentNode.Children.Count();
    <ul>
        @foreach (var story in currentNode.Children.Where("Visible").Take(pageIndex * pageSize))
        {

            <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="@story.Url" class="st-text">@story.Name</a></li>
        }
    </ul>
}
}
 else
{
selected = CurrentPage.Children.Where("Visible");
max_pages = CurrentPage.Children.Count();
if (selected.Any())
{
        <ul>
            @foreach (var story in selected.Take(pageIndex * pageSize))
            {
                <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="@story.Url" class="st-text">@story.Name</a></li>
            }
        </ul>

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

First, this:

```
class="\""st-text"\"
```

prevents correct parsing of the line and messes up the following. You probably meant

```
class="st-text"
```

or

```
class='"st-text"'
```

Then, all `@ViewData` that are already in the context of C# code, must be replaced with just `ViewData` (which is all of them).

Answer (score -1):

compare your main view's all opening and closing bracket too.

```
   @inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
   @{
    var langstr = "All";
    var pageSize = 6;
    var max_pages=0;
    try
    {
        if (ViewData["storylang"] == null)
        {
            langstr = "";
        }
        else
        {
            langstr = ViewData["storylang"].ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        langstr = "";
    }

    var pageIndex = (int)ViewData["page_index"];
    dynamic selected;

    if (ViewData["curpage"] != null)
    {

        var id = (int)ViewData["curpage"];
        var currentNode = Umbraco.TypedContent(id);
        selected = currentNode.Children.Where("Visible");


        if(langstr != "")
        {
            selected = currentNode.Children.Where("Visible").Where("language=\"" + @langstr + "\"");
            max_pages = currentNode.Children.Count();

            <ul>
            @foreach (var story in selected.Take(pageIndex * pageSize))
            {
                <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="@story.Url" class="st-text">@story.Name</a></li>
            }
            </ul>

        }

    }
    else
    {
        selected = CurrentPage.Children.Where("Visible");
        max_pages = CurrentPage.Children.Count();
        if(selected.Any()){
        <ul>
        @foreach (var story1 in selected.Take(pageIndex * pageSize))
        {
        <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="@story1.Url" **class="st-text"**>@story1.Name</a></li>
        }
        </ul>

    }
}
}
```

Comment: No, it does not, I have checked. The entire `else` block is not highlighted as code, all `@ViewData`s are underlined as errors and a bracket mismatch error is displayed. Also you highlighted with `**` the wrong place of the code where you didn't in fact change anything, and the entire code has nothing to do with your advice to "compare your main view's all opening and closing bracket".

Comment: If you chnage your class assigning syntax from class="\" "st-text" \" to class="st-text" it will match with your bracket

Comment: No, it will not. Neither [in VS2012](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2p83G.png) nor [in VS2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muf2C.png).